# Find those points of S that have no neighborhoods in which the equation $f(x, y) = 0$ can be solved for y in terms of x .

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Define $f$ in $R^2$ by
$$f(x, y) = 2x^3 - 3x^2 + 2y^3 + 3y^2$$

(a) Find the four points in $R^2$ at which the gradient of $f$ is zero. Show that $f$ has exactly one local maximum and one local minimum in $R^2$.

(b) Let S be the set of all $(x, y) \in R^2$ at which $f(x, y) = 0$. Find those points of S that have no neighborhoods in which the equation $f(x, y) = 0$ can be solved for y in terms of x (or for x in terms of y).

Describe S as precisely as you can.

I have solved the first part of the problem. Having Problem with the second part.
I assume that we have to apply Implicit function theorem here....

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$f(x,y)=(x+y)(2x^2-2xy+2y^2-3x+3y)\ .$$
It follows that the set $S\colon\>f(x,y)=0$ is the union of the line $\ell\colon \>x+y=0$ and the quadric
$$Q:\quad g(x,y):=2x^2-2xy+2y^2-3x+3y=0\ .$$
Writing $x:={1\over2}+\bar x$, $\>y:=-{1\over2}+\bar y$ we obtain the description
$$Q:\quad 2\bar x^2-2\bar x\bar y+2\bar y^2={3\over2}$$
of $Q$, which indicates that $Q$ is an ellipse with center $M:=\bigl({1\over2},-{1\over2}\bigr)\in \ell$ and axes at a $45^\circ$ angle, i.e., aligned with $\ell$. The two curves intersect at the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,-1)$ which are true singularities of $S$. These two points have already appeared in your calculations as saddle points of $f$, the reason being that $f$ changes sign when crossing $\ell$ or $Q$.

We now look at 
$$\nabla f(x,y)=(x+y)\nabla g(x,y)+g(x,y) (1,1)\ .$$
When $(x,y)\in\ell\setminus Q$ we have $\nabla f(x,y)=g(x,y)(1,1)\ne0$. This shows that all points on $\ell$ other than the two points $(0,0)$ and $(1,-1)$ are *regular* points of $S$. This means that each such point $(x_0,y_0)$ is the center of a rectangular window $W$ such that $\ell\cap W$ can be written in at least one of the forms $$y=\phi(x), \quad{\rm resp.,}\quad x=\psi(y)\ .\tag{1}$$
On the other hand, when $(x,y)\in Q\setminus \ell$ we have $\nabla f(x,y)=(x+y)\nabla g(x,y)\ne0$, because $x+y\ne0$, and
$$\nabla g(x,y)=(4x-2y-3, \>4y-2x+3)$$
 vanishes only at the point $M\notin Q$. It follows that all points of $Q\setminus\ell$ are regular points of $S$ as well.

To sum it all up: Apart from the two singularities $(0,0)$ and $(1,-1)$ the set $S$ has at all points a local description of the form $(1)$. Here is a contour plot of $f$:

[image]